# how to add a class to a div in a loop

Tags: jquery

I want to add in a loop to a span a class but it does not work.

What is wrong with it? `attr({'class':'folder_name' })`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var section = $('section');
    var text = section.text().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        text[i] = '<span>' + text[i].attr({'class': 'folder_name'}) +
            '</span>';
    }
    section.html(text.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: Why not use [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)? But it still won't work because `text[i]` is not a jQuery object; it's a string.

Comment: `text[i]` is a string...... You should just set the class on the span.....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the element has not yet been created when you try setting the class on the element.

The following code should fix it because the class is added as a string while building the HTML for the `span`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var section = $('section');
    var text = section.text().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        text[i] = '<span class="' + 'folder_name' + '">' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    section.html(text.join(' '));
});
```

As stated on a comment your question, you may be better off using a more jQuery like approach like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var section = $('section');
    var text = section.text().split(' ');
    section.html('');
    text.forEach(function(t){
        section.add($('<span>' + t + '</span>').addClass('folder_name'))
    })
});
```